# Tikz specify bottom part of the node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know if it is possible to align the bottom part of a node with a specific point. I already have a code, but it has two problems: first the alignement is not perfect, I don't know why, and also the code is not very natural to write (maybe a library already do the math for me?).

Goal: align the C box like that, without the error (and possibly with a nice code):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=2cm,
    align=center,
    fill=red!50!white,
  },
  ]%
  \node[box] (A) {$A$};
  \node[box, below=of A] (B) {$B$\\multiline};
  \path let \p1=($(A.north)-(B.south)$) in node[box, right=of A.north east,anchor=north west, minimum height={\y1}, inner sep=0pt] (C) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got an error because you have a non-ASCII character in your code, but otherwise the approach is fine I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit 1:

If you are *really* annoyed with the 0.01411cm of extra space that is generated, you can use the following to draw the box C without borders:

`\node[box,fit=(A)(B), right=of A.north east,anchor=north west,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,outer sep=\pgflinewidth/2, draw=none] (C) {$C$};`

Or the following with the default border (`line width=0.4pt`) thickness:

`\node[box,fit=(A)(B), right=of A.north east,anchor=north west,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=\pgflinewidth, draw=blue] (C) {$C$};`

**Note:** rounding will probably occur as we are talking about very tiny numbers and pdf viewers uses whole pixels so you might *feel* it is not perfect to the precision of the pixel.

[image: Output updated]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=2cm,
    align=center,
    fill=red!50!white,
  },
  ]%
  \node[box] (A) {$A$};
  \node[box, below=of A] (B) {$B$\\multiline};
  \node[box,fit=(A)(B), right=of A.north east,anchor=north west,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,outer sep=\pgflinewidth/2, draw=none] (C) {$C$};
  \node[box,fit=(A)(B), right=of C.north east,anchor=north west,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=\pgflinewidth, draw=blue] (D) {With border};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

### Original:

Use the `fit` option as you have imported it.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=2cm,
    align=center,
    fill=red!50!white,
  },
  ]%
  \node[box] (A) {$A$};
  \node[box, below=of A] (B) {$B$\\multiline};
  \node[box,fit=(A)(B), right=of A.north east,anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] (C) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, it's possible to fit that way?! Amazing, thanks! But there is still this strange thin space below, that appears if you remove the border of the image, any idea why?

Comment: @tobiasBora, I have updated the answer, please, have a look at it.

Comment: Great thanks a lot!